# multer-gridfs-storage (node:4041) DeprecationWarning: collection.insert is deprecated. Use insertOne, insertMany or bulkWrite instead

Tags: node.js, multer-gridfs-storage

> **multer-gridfs-storage** (node:4041) DeprecationWarning: `collection.insert` is deprecated. Use `insertOne`, `insertMany` or `bulkWrite` instead.

How can I avoid this deprecation warning?

Comment: By not using `collection.insert`.

Answer (score 0):

Warning comes from `mongodb` driver itself and according to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1693 has been fixed in `3.1.7`.

So upgrade your driver to latest version.